# Class 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow' cannot be indexed because it has no default property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What i am having trouble doing is set the current parameter to the current row at a specific column like e.row[column index]

```
    For Each trow As TableRow In table.Rows

            cmd1.CommandText = "dbo.directway"
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd1.Connection = conn



            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tour", trow(0))
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tourname", trow(1))
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@taskname", trow(2))
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deptdate", trow(3))
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@duedate", trow(4))
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tasktype", trow(5))
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", trow(8))
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agent", trow(6))
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@completed", trow(7))


            conn.Open()
            cmd1.BeginExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()



        Next
```

Class 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow' cannot be indexed because it has no default property.

Comment: What specific trouble do you get? Or what is the error msg?

Comment: What you have looks fine to me; does it not work?  Does it throw an exception?  A little detail here might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are so many things wrong here ...

First, you have a Command object named `cmd1`, but you are adding parameters to an object named `cmd`. **Turn on Option Explicit**. Second, VB.NET uses parenthesis around indexes, not square brackets. Third, you are calling variable `e` instead of `trow`, and you should be referencing trow(0), trow(1), etc. Fix these things up and then post an update.